# How to combine JaCoCo reports from multiple sub projects

Tags: scala, sbt, code-coverage, jacoco

I have a working setup for a simple SBT build but now I am dealing with a multi project build. At the moment SBT jacoco:cover produces reports inside each sub project but I would like to have an aggregate at the root level /target/scala-2.xx/jacoco.

Comment: Feature request has been submitted here: https://github.com/sbt/jacoco4sbt/issues/11

Answer (score 3):

Jacoco has jacoco:merge ant target which you can integrate with SBT to merge reports from subprojects.

```
<jacoco:merge destfile="merged.exec">
    <fileset dir="dir_common_location" includes="*.exec"/>
</jacoco:merge>
```

- Put individual report from each project in a common location.
- Merge those report to a single merged.exec

Comment: Have to take look using that this way as jacoco4sbt supports merge only in it-jacoco configuration.